# doxygen: two makros in one description box

Tags: documentation, doxygen, code-documentation

I want to connect two related define-makros in my doxygen HTML-documentation in such a way, that they are shown in a single description box.

I hope I can describe clearly how it should look like: Normally every define statement gets its own description box using `/** @define <description> */`. This results in a description box with the code part in the title line of the box and a short description in the box content.

What I want to do now is to connect two define statements in such a way that they are shown in a single box with a common description. Does anybody knows a way to realize that?

PS: Maby it gets a little bit clearer with this ASCII graphic.

`+-------------------------+
 | #define PORT    1       |
 | #define PORTDIR 0       |
 +-------------------------+
 | output port definitions |
 +-------------------------+`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group #defines using `@name @{ .. @}`. Here is a small example. Looks best when also setting `SUBGROUPING` to `NO` in the configuration file.

```
/** @file
 *  File documentation
 */

/** @name Output ports definitions
 *  @brief Brief description for the group.
 *  @{
 */
#define PORT    1 /**< @brief The port number */
#define PORTDIR 0 /**< @brief The port direction */
/** @} */

/** @brief A lonely macro */
#define LONELY  2
```

When you omit the documentation for the individual macros you get close the what you requested, only the documentation is above and not below the group.